# HTML multiple fileread

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" required>
<input type="file" name="img2" id="img2">
<input type="file" name="img3" id="img3">
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img4">
```

jQuery Code:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
                if($("#img"+i).val() != ''){
                    file = document.getElementById('img' + i).files[0];
                    fileread(file);
                }
            }

function fileread(file){
        var result = '';
        reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
                result = reader.result;
                //return result;
                localStorage.setItem("lostimage1", result);

            }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

I want to read multiple files when user click on submit button. but it not working. How can I resolve this error? please help me.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a change Event on those files. `reader.readAsDataURL(file);`? It's all there by its lonesome. What are you doing with the files should be my question? If you just need to assign them to an `ImageElement.src` then do that. If you want the uploads on the Sever, consider `FormData` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery and each() method I suggest this:

```js
var checkValue;
var valueArray=[];
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  $('input').each(function(){    
    checkValue=$(this).val();
    if(checkValue===''){
      return;
    }
    valueArray.push(checkValue);    
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1" required>
<input type="file" name="img2" id="img2">
<input type="file" name="img3" id="img3">
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img4">
  <button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach `click` event to `<input type="submit">`, call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent `<form>` submission, use `.each()` to iterate `<input type="file">` elements, pass `this.files[0]` to `readfile` function.

Adjust within `FileReader` `load` handler to not overwrite same key at `localStorage`.

`FileReader` throws an error if a `Blob` or `File` object is not passed as parameter to `.readAsDataURL()`, for example`, if``is clicked and`fileread`is called in loop and one of``elements`.files`property doe not contain`File`object in`FileList`. Check if element`.files`has`.length`greater than`0`before calling`fileread`referencing the`.files[0]`property of the current`` element.

```
$(function() {
  function fileread(file, id) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      localStorage.setItem("lostimage" + id, reader.result);    
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  $("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(":file[id^=img]").each(function() {
      if (this.files.length) fileread(this.files[0], this.id.replace(/\D/g, ""))
    })
  });
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1Sec8uWlK2pbXMTlfpCj?p=preview

Comment: FIRST ARE READ OTHERWISE ALL NULL.

Comment: @ShahRushabh What do you mean?

Comment: when I am alerting it alerting img1 but not alerting img2 but all field are filled with the file.

Comment: can you please check on my web server if you can then I will share my website.

Comment: `reader` was being defined globally. Use `var reader = new FileReader()`, see updated post http://plnkr.co/edit/5ddglEjOu3yKVYiCPIT4?p=info